# Import in isomorphic app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

That doesn't make any sense:

```
import {Dispatcher} from 'flux';
console.log('Dispatcher', Dispatcher)
```

I'm using [the same boilerplate](https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit) as usual, the same node version, same compilers, same approaches etc...
But the `console.log` above correctly logs `Dispatcher` function on server side and `undefined` on client side.

If i'm doing this:

```
import Flux from 'flux';
console.log('Flux', Flux)
```

Server side logs:
`Flux { Dispatcher: [Function: Dispatcher] }`

Client side:

```
actions: undefined
constants: {
  TEST_ACTION: "TEST_ACTION" 
}
dispatcher: undefined
```

Apparently, i'm making just some stupid simple mistake somewhere, but i can't find it.

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "6.5.0",
    "fetch-plus": "3.8.1",
    "fetch-plus-bearerauth": "3.5.0",
    "fetch-plus-json": "3.6.0",
    "file-loader": "0.8.5",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "keymirror": "^0.1.0",
    "koa": "1.2.0",
    "koa-proxy": "0.5.0",
    "koa-static": "2.0.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "0.14.7",
    "react-inline-css": "2.1.0",
    "react-router": "2.0.0",
    "react-transmit": "3.1.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "6.6.5",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.5.0",
    "concurrently": "2.0.0",
    "forever": "0.15.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-uglifycss": "^1.0.6",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "just-wait": "1.0.5",
    "webpack": "1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.14.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.0.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

omg... 
import looks like that:

```
import {Dispatcher} from 'flux';
```

this file is located in folder "flux", i've created `index.js` file within this folder to make it easier to import `Actions.js` and `Dispatcher.js`. For some reason webpack assumed that on client side `from 'flux'` means import from this folder.